# Why don't functions have parameters listed in their defintions?

Tags: perl

I have just recently begun playing around with Perl and I was hoping that someone could explain to me why functions in Perl *don't* have parameters listed in their definitions, is there some language justification for this?

It seems to me that the lack of parameters in the definition makes for code that is *harder* to understand. Any thoughts comments or insights into this would be appreciated.

```
sub func
{
   my ($a, $b) = @_;
}
```

vs

```
sub func($a, $b)
{

}
```

Comment: I am sure no one is claiming anymore that this design decision has not been a mistake.

Comment: @Thilo I am new to Perl as I mentioned, I only encountered this issue about an hour ago; so I don't know any history about it.

Comment: It's just how Perl is. I know with a language like ML, you always only pass one parameter and it is up to the function to unpack it.

Comment: @squiguy But at least there is *something* in the function defintion, it is just completely absent. It is really misleading.

Comment: Yes, it's not as clear as other languages I think. I know you can have formal prototypes, but this is restrictive as well. [`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) is a great reference for more information on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl 6 provides a way to do so

http://perl6.org/archive/rfc/57.html

with syntax like

```
sub foo ($x, $y) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is promising, thanks.

Comment: Don't get too excited, though. Seeing that you don't know any Perl history, it is only fair to warn you of the fact that Perl 6 has been in development since 2000. It should be ready in time for Christmas, we just cannot be sure of the year.

Comment: Also, Perl 6 is not a replacement for Perl 5.

Comment: @squiguy Can you explain this a little more ?

Comment: Perl 6 is not syntax-compatible with Perl 5. It is a whole new language.

Comment: As always in Perl, there's some modules on CPAN that will do this for you. I like https://metacpan.org/module/Method::Signatures::Simple but there is https://metacpan.org/module/Method::Signatures and others for more complex signatures.